# Apache Errors, What do they mean?

Tags: apache

i am getting these error messages in my apache log but i have no idea what they mean. any ideas?

```
[Thu Jan 10 17:50:20 2013] [warn] Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5'
[Thu Jan 10 17:50:20 2013] [warn] Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5'
[Thu Jan 10 17:50:20 2013] [warn] Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5'
[Thu Jan 10 17:50:20 2013] [error] [client 66.249.78.171] [info] [pid=23974 euid=0 egid=99] suexec.cpp(280): setrlimit(2): 9 set to  33554432/33554432 (soft/hard) bytes
[Thu Jan 10 17:50:20 2013] [error] [client 66.249.78.171] [info] [pid=23974 euid=0 egid=99] suexec.cpp(280): setrlimit(2): 2 set to  4294967295/4294967295 (soft/hard) bytes
[Thu Jan 10 17:50:20 2013] [error] [client 66.249.78.171] [info] [pid=23974 euid=0 egid=99] suexec.cpp(280): setrlimit(2): 3 set to  4294967295/4294967295 (soft/hard) bytes
[Thu Jan 10 17:50:20 2013] [error] [client 66.249.78.171] [info] [pid=23974 euid=0 egid=99] suexec.cpp(280): setrlimit(2): 9 set to  176160768/176160768 (soft/hard) bytes
[Thu Jan 10 17:50:20 2013] [error] [client 66.249.78.171] [info] [pid=23974 euid=0 egid=99] suexec.cpp(280): setrlimit(2): 2 set to  4294967295/4294967295 (soft/hard) bytes
[Thu Jan 10 17:50:20 2013] [error] [client 66.249.78.171] [info] [pid=23974 euid=0 egid=99] suexec.cpp(280): setrlimit(2): 3 set to  4294967295/4294967295 (soft/hard) bytes`
```

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5'`

Something is wrong with your php setup (php files probably aren't working if you get that message). x-mapp-php5 is likely mapped to ".php" in your Apache configuration, so when the server tries to serve a php file it is looking for something that handles the x-mapp-php5 and not finding it, due to some misconfiguration.

`[error] [client 66.249.78.171] [info] [pid=23974 euid=0 egid=99] suexec.cpp(280): setrlimit(2): 9 set to  33554432/33554432 (soft/hard) bytes`

pid, euid, and egid are the process id, user id, and group id. suexec.cpp indicates that something is trying to change a userid to root (euid=0). setrlimit indicates an attempt to set system resource limits.

In other words, something in your Apache setup is trying to do things at a system level that it can't/shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for the informed reply. Our website is at http://bitly.com/OWhQ3H but it seems to be working ok. I will need to talk to our system admins who don't necessarily know about wordpress which is what we are using. They manage the server. Are there any specific instructions I need to give them to rectify these errors? thanks again. Andy

Comment: If you do a search on the first error `Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5'`, many hits also refer to WordPress. Unfortunately, they are mostly questions from people working with an external hosting service that either doesn't support them or whose solutions don't work for them. I haven't used WordPress myself, so I can't point you towards anything specific. Those log lines should be enough for your sysadmins to at least look into their php/Apache configuration and, if not directly identify the issue, provide you some feedback on the kinds of things to look for in the WordPress setup.

Comment: I would also recommend clicking around the site from a known IP address while monitoring the active log file. This way you may narrow down which actions on the site are causing the errors in question. Better yet, if you have the site on an equivalent test server, clicking around there would avoid having to filter out public traffic while monitoring the logs.